# Logging into WSO2 from an android device

Tags: java, android, wso2

I followed the set up instructions in the WSO2 documentation.

I have the following in my CommonUtilities.java

```
public static boolean DEBUG_MODE_ENABLED = true;
public static boolean LOCAL_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED = true;
public static boolean GCM_ENABLED = false;

public static String SERVER_IP = "172.16.0.186";

public static String SERVER_PORT = "9443";
public static String SERVER_PROTOCOL = "https://";
public static String API_VERSION = "1.0.0";
```

When I try to log in I get the following crash:

> W/System.err(29531): java.io.IOException: Wrong version of key store.
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.bc.BcKeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(BcKeyStoreSpi.java:805)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:589) W/System.err(29531):
>     at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.getCertifiedHttpClient(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:56)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.postData(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:238)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.sendWithTimeWait(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:107)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.getClientKey(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:89)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.AuthenticationActivity$12.doInBackground(AuthenticationActivity.java:444)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.AuthenticationActivity$12.doInBackground(AuthenticationActivity.java:1)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) W/System.err(29531):
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   W/System.err(29531):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   V/ServerUtils(29531): 172.16.0.186Posting '{password=xxx,
>   username=leahmckelvey}' to
>   https://172.16.0.186:9443/emm/api/devices/clientkey
>   V/ServerUtils(29531): Posting
>   'password=xxx&username=leahmckelvey' to
>   https://172.16.0.186:9443/emm/api/devices/clientkey
>   E/ServerUtils(29531): Failed to register on attempt 1
>   E/ServerUtils(29531): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.postData(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:279)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.sendWithTimeWait(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:107)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.utils.HTTPConnectorUtils.getClientKey(HTTPConnectorUtils.java:89)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.AuthenticationActivity$12.doInBackground(AuthenticationActivity.java:444)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   org.wso2.emm.agent.AuthenticationActivity$12.doInBackground(AuthenticationActivity.java:1)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) E/ServerUtils(29531):
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   E/ServerUtils(29531):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   E/AuthenticationActivity(29531): The result is null in
>   getOauthClientInfo()

Is there something I overlooked?  This is a testing environment.  I am trying to set up a demo for my company, but I can't seem to get past the login.

Comment: You should probably add the java and android tag (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: Thanks.  I added them.